# Can I paraphrase "none" into "no one" in this context?

Tags: pronouns

> Mio had no money, and Pat also had **none**.

Can I paraphrase that into this?

> Mio had no money, and Pat also had **no one.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. By itself, "no one" means "no person."

Answer (score 2):

No. The second *none* refers to money, not people.